# My web project with 5 ML models is very large

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning

In my django project I use 5 ML models and for load certain model I write something like this:

```
model = pickle.load(open("AI_models/xgboost_model1.sav", "rb"))
```

But in this way all models are located on my project and they take a lot of memory and it slow down my web app after deploy on google cloud as a docker container.

Can I deploy my models anywhere on cloud with link for each models and after that use them like this:

```
model = pickle.load(open("https://example/xgboost_model1.sav"))
```

?

So I need that my models are located anywhere but not in root folder of my project.

Thank for any ideas.

Comment: You could look into uploading your model to [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/models-uploading) , but I doubt this will solve your problem. It doesn't matter where you load your model from, if ultimately it is being loaded into your main memory, it will slow down your app!

Comment: So how can I normally organize the interaction between my web app and my ML models?

Comment: You could think of using a larger container/ splitting into multiple containers. Finally, the slow down could be from the time taken by these models to run inference on your inputs, for which the only choice is to use faster/simpler models